# Get user information of prestashop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I want to get customer information from prestashop into wordpress in `themes/functions.php`. 
I have serach that prestashop give user information in this method

```
$id = $this->context->customer->id_customer;
```

I have included prestahsop with `config/settings.inc.php` in my themes/functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

If you have included config files and you have customer id, just do this:

```
$customer = new Customer((int)$id);
```

And you have all info. But keep in mind if you need info about customer address - you must get customer delivery address id or invoice address id and use same:   `$address = new Address((int)$id_address_invoice);`

Comment: You can get customer id if logged using cart: $cart->id_customer. And have you tried to include init.php and config.inc?

Answer (score 0):

To access Prestashop's function and context you just need to add `config.inc.php` file. You will find that file here

> config/config.inc.php

You can add this file in Wordpress's main configuration file that is `wp-load.php`